# How do I remove the shortcut buttons/toolbar from emacs?

Tags: emacs

After upgrading from Ubuntu 13 -> 14.04 `emacs` now wastes valuable screen space with silly buttons. How can I go back to a "buttonless" version of emacs?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit your `~/.emacs` or our `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file and add this line

```
(tool-bar-mode 0)
```

This will prevent the toolbar for showing again.

Answer (score 4):

`Options` menu -> `Show/Hide` -> `Tool-bar` -> `None`

`Options` -> `Save Options`